# GitHub project deployment failed on azure

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-web-app-service

I want to deploy my .Net project from GitHub repository to the azure server.

In **Deployment options** I am getting Building failed error.

Here are screen shots of my Deployment details and Logs

**1- Deployment Details:**

[image]

**2- Activity Log:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description and logs, I found you have error in MSbuild step.

The error shows some files not found in your project. I suggest you could exclude the related files in the csproj file or make sure the related files is in your project.

Besides, I suggest you could firstly clone the project to your local and test it , make sure the project could build well without any error then publish to the GitHub and deploy to the azure.

---

Update:

I also write a test demo on my computer and I reproduce your error.

Error image:

[image]

I think in your project you have inclued the bin and obj folder into your project and then you push the project to the github.

Like below:

[image]

After you push the project to the github, the csporj file will include all the bin and obj references.

Like below:

[image]

This is the reason about your MSBuild fail.

So I suggest you uninclude all the bin and obj folder in the local and push to the github again. Then it will work well.

Comment: project is running fine on local. Also it gets deploy using publish settings but with that method it alway needs to to remove all migrations and re-enable migrations. I know that one is bad approach

Comment: Any update? If you feel my answer is useful /helpful. Please mark it as an answer so that other folks could benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

Azure looks in your site/repository/packages folder for all the packages your app uses. By looking through it you will find that visual studio doesn't deploy all of the files from your local packages folder to the azure one. MSBuild needs these files when you push to git and trigger a build. Ftp into your azure site and look for the packages folder. Upload every missing file (dll) from your local folder to the azure one. This worked for me and now I can trigger a build and deployment from bitbucket to azure app service upon a push.

Additionally, if you have other projects in your VS solution and you are using VS to build those projects and then put the dll into your main projects bin folder, that will cause a missing file error also. I create a folder in my packages folder and link the dll to my main folder from there. That way when you perform the fix above, the file needed by your main project is in the packages folder also.

I hope this helps!